# iOS App Not Building in Corona

Tags: ios, build, lua, coronasdk

I am wondering if there are any reasons corona does not ever finish "Performing Build" while building for iOS. I know having a poor internet connection (which I do not happen to have) can slow it down -- but not to the extent where I need to keep my computer running for hours...

A while back I was having problems with my provisioning profiles and I had switched to a new computer, and corona would not allow me to build. I have now though fixed that problem, and moved onto this one. A couple of months ago, before this problem, it was working fine and I was able to build for my iPad, and publish to the app store. Now I cannot release my next update or test any future version which is a huge setback.

Please let me know on how I can solve this problem!

Comment: Do you use latest Xcode and Corona builds? I had a similar issue and I updated Xcode and it worked fine. Btw, you can also try to build for android and see if it differs

Comment: I use the latest Xcode and it does work for android. For the newest corona build, do you mean the daily build? I have Corona: Version 2013.1137 (2013.6.7)

Comment: I tried the newest build -- still did not work, thanks though. I'm open to any other ideas!

Comment: If it works fine with android, the problem must be related to Xcode, do you check the termianl? Maybe you have the same issue with me

Comment: You were right! Thanks, this is the warning the terminal gave me:                  WARNING: Could not find certificate for identity (iPhone Distribution: NAME HERE) whose user id is: ----------

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it works fine with android, the problem must be related to Xcode, do you check the terminal? Maybe you have the same issue with me